# For every imperative function, is there a functional counterpart with identical performance or even instructions?

Tags: compilers, functional-programming, haskell, imperative-programming

Currently, I haven't learned about a functional language that can achieve the same performance as C/C++. And I have learned that some languages that favor functional programming to imperative programming, such as Scala and Rust, use imperative ways to implement their library functions for better efficiency.

So here comes my question, on today's comptuters that execute imperative instructions, is this a limitation of the compiler or functional programming itself? For every imperative function with no side effects, either in a language without GC such as C/C++/Rust/assembly or one with GC such as Java, is there a pure functional counterpart in Haskell, Scala, etc. that can be compiled to run with identical performance in time and space (not just asymptotic but exactly the same) or even to the same instructions, with an optimal functional compiler that utilizes all modern and even undiscovered optimization techniques such as tail recursion, laziness, static analysis, formal verification, and so on which I don't know about?

I am aware of the equivalence between λ-computable and Turing computable, but but I couldn't find an answer to this question online. If there is, please share a compiler example or a proof. If not, please explain why and show a counter-example. Or is this a non-trivial open question?

---

**Supplementary edits as suggested by [Andrej Bauer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/1329/andrej-bauer):**

To be more specific, here are 2 examples that led into thinking about this question.

For example, tail recursion and accumulators can improve the performance of some recursive functions to be identical to an imperative implementation using `for`. In some cases they might even have the same instructions.

Another example is about laziness in Haskell. Laziness can help avoid unnecessary copying of data structures and make performance better. However, laziness leaves wrappings, closures, etc. in the runtime and still can't make the program as fast as an imperative implementation where there are no such things. So I am wondering whether such things can be statically removed before runtime during compilation.

**Supplementary edits as suggested by [Nearoo](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/95159/nearoo):**

The question can also be stated in this way: is there a language that supports both pure functional programming and imperative programming, paired with an optimized compiler, in which every function with no side effects implemented imperatively can be replaced with one implemented purely functionally, at no cost of performance or even compiled to the same instructions?

Comment: The first paragraph makes it sound as if you commited the following logical falacy: "I have not learned about efficient functional languages, therefore they must be inefficient." You may wish to rephrase that. Regarding your question, do you really want "identical performance"? Even different C++ compilers don't give "identical performance".

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sorry for any unprofessional statements Professor. I am relatively new to functional programming and type theory but I am quite insterested in this field.

Comment: @AndrejBauer This question came to me when I was learning and thinking about laziness in Haskell. Laziness can help avoid unnecessary copying of data structures and make performance better. However, if I am not wrong, laziness leaves wrappings, closures, etc. in the runtime and still can't make the program as fast as an imperative implementation where there are no such things. So I am wondering whether such things can be statically removed before runtime during compilation. And in a broader sense it becomes the question above, which is whether they can achieve identical performance.

Comment: Those are all very good questions that you make in your comment. Your question is perhaps a little less clear about what you are really asking. One cannot always statically make all optimizations one wishes (because one quickly gets to undecidable problems), but good compilers (both functional and imperative) can do a lot. Haskell already performs many non-trivial optimizations.

Comment: This was already touched on by others, but performance in terms of instructions is strictly not part of a language. So asking "is there a functional version of that imperative function that is identical in terms of instructions?" is a question not about languages or the imperative/functional property - it's a question about compilers. You're basically asking "are there two compilers, one for an imperative, one for a functional language, that produce the same output for some semantically equivalent functions?"

Comment: @Nearoo Yeah this is close to what I am asking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Performance is not a property of language, it is a property of specific programs within a language. Some languages might be very fast at some things and slow at others.

   For example, Chez-Scheme can sometimes find performance comparable to C, not because the language is more efficient, but because defensive practices that programmers often use in C are less necessary in scheme.

   Likewise, there are times when Haskell can do very efficient parallelism or concurrency, not because it is faster than C, but because the immutability guarantees of the language allow the programmer to avoid things like locks and other synchronization techniques.

   And, performance varies from implementation to implementation. I can hand-roll a C interpreter, but it will certainly not be fast. C is not fast, GCC and Clang are.
2. What is considered a "functional" language? Every practical functional language has some facilities for mutable state: OCaml, Haskell, Scala, Lisp, Scheme, etc. Tail recursion gives something roughly equivalent to mutation inside of a for-loop. But when this is not enough, functional languages give the programmer access to mutable state. In the case of Haskell, this is controlled by the type system, so there is never *implicit mutable state*, but mutation is very much allowed and even encouraged in Haskell. Look at any Haskell code, and you will see the IO monad everywhere. Likewise, ML languages distinguish between types `T` and `ref T`, so you can tell by the types whether a variable is mutable or not.
3. There is no "optimal" compiler, thanks to Rice's theorem. All compilers, imperative or functional, are "best effort:" the use conservative approximations to optimize code.

   If we had an optimal compiler, the answer would be that every program always ran using the most efficient instructions possible, and it wouldn't matter what language you coded your problem in. The optimal sequence of instructions computing a problem does not depend on the source language. But if we had this, then this compiler would compile every non-halting program into `while(0)`, which means we could detect non-halting programs, which is impossible.
4. For Turing Machines and the lambda calculus, I think it is fairly trivial to implement a lambda calculus interpreter for Turing Machines that is *asymptotically* equivalent to a universal Turing-machine. Big-O complexity isn't what people mean when they say "Functional languages are slow". Usually they are talking about constant overhead, which is very different. We don't have as good of ways to mathematically model this, so we usually just end up using experiments to measure precise performance.

Comment: "Performance is not a property of language" some languages map well to machines, or are easy to analyse in important ways, leading to typically fast implementations, while others do not and are hard to implement fast.

Comment: Right, but what's fast on one chipset might be slow on another, and tons is implementation dependent. I'd be willing to bet that the naive, totally unoptimized version of a C compiler produces code that's slower than most higher-level languages.